# Parsing joda datetime in salesforce

Tags: apex

I am getting an error when I am executing this piece of code.

```
String ss_time = '2015-10-21T10:04:04.000Z'; 
c.Assignment_Start_Time__c =DateTime.valueOf(ss_time);
```

> **Error Message :**  System.TypeException: Invalid date/time:
>   2015-10-21T10:04:04.000Z

How should I set the datetime properly. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the T from the string value, for example:

```
String ss_time = '2015-10-21 10:04:04.000Z'; 
c.Assignment_Start_Time__c =DateTime.valueOf(ss_time);
```

Note that the returned value is in GMT, see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_valueOf) for details.